# Basics of miking a marching snare

Tags: microphone, drum

I've seen a lot of Drum Core International soloist videos that have awesome quality of sound. Optimally I figured there would be one mike for the top and one for the bottom to get the full range of sound. Rim clicks and rim shots tend to have different projections, and I want to capture as much of the range of sounds as possible Any good tips about mike placement, distance, etc.?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest **one on top**, a few inches above the head, only slightly turned to the surface of the snare. Then **one on the bottom**, also a few inches from the bottom of the drum. Basically you just have to try different positions and distances, because that varies depending on the specific type of snare you're trying to record.

If you're going to hold the drum while standing, you obviously can't use an overhead mic. But if you have it on a stand, I'd suggest adding a third mic **overhead** so you can get a bit more ambience.

Answer (score 1):

I think one on top and one on the bottom are enough.  Use good quality dynamic mics, and they should pick up everything.

If possible, run the signals from the mics thru an oscilliscope to make sure that the signals from the top and bottom are not out of phase - if that's not possible, use your ears.